# ¿Cómo mostrar contenido de un radio seleccionado automáticamente con un switch en la misma página - PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

Encontré algo parecido pero muy distinto a lo que deseo lograr, en la siguiente pregunta [Ocultar y mostrar un div al hacer click en un radiobutton con javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6649/ocultar-y-mostrar-un-div-al-hacer-click-en-un-radiobutton-con-javascript)

Realmente quiero evitar ese uso de solo ocultar contenidos mediante CSS con el `display: none;` en vez de eso quiero hacer que se muestre de forma automática la información seleccionada de un `radio` mediante un `switch` de PHP.

Mediante así solo se llama el contenido deseado en vez de tenerlo todo el contenido oculto mediante CSS.

Mediante PHP genere el siguiente contenido HTML

```
<?php
$r =array(
    1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
    2 => 'PayPal',
    3 => 'Tarjeta de credito',
);

foreach ($r as $key => $value) {

  if(isset($_SESSION['datos_form']['radio']) && $_SESSION['datos_form']['radio'] == $key ) {
        echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'"  checked="checked" >';
        echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
    } else {
        echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'" >';
        echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
    }

}
?>
```

Y mediante un `switch` de PHP llamar una plantilla según el radio seleccionado de forma automática.

> Si la información fuera enviada desde una página a otra página sería fácil rescatar el valor, y ese valor mostrarlo en el `switch`. *Pero el problema es que toda esta información está en la misma página y todo se debe ejecutar sin refrescar la página.*

```
switch (variable) {
    case 'value':
        # code... tarjeta de crédito o débito 
        include 'form_credit_card.php';
        break;

    case 'value':
        # code... Pago con paypal
        include 'payment_paypal.php';
        break;

    case 'value':
        # code... transferencia bancaria
        include 'wire_transfer.php';
        break;

    default:
        # code...
        echo "Hubo un error inesperado en la forma de pago seleccionada, vuelva intentarlo más tarde";
        break;
}
```

En jQuery he realizado algo parecido, pero muy lejos de lo que deseo lograr, lo único que he logrado mostrar es el `label` del radio seleccionado.

```
function show_step(step){
    var data = $( "#form" ).serialize();
    var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + step;
    // recuperamos el label del radio button seleccionado
    var valor_radio = $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').next("label").text();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data
    })
    .done(function( resp ) {
        // si todo va bien
        // ocultamos los pasos
        $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
        // mostramos el paso correspondiente
        $('#step'+step).fadeIn("slow");
        // mostramos el radio button seleccionado
        $('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);
        animacion(step);
    });
};
```

Entonces mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo llamar las plantilla de pago según el valor del `radio` seleccionado desde un `switch` de forma automática en la misma página?

> **Nota:** Algunas de las plantillas de pago, tienen código PHP por ejemplo la plantilla de forma de pago de PayPal que lleva el valor de la compra en su formulario, y la plantilla de tarjeta de crédito tiene códigos de javascript usando pasarela de pago de Stripe.

Comment: Quieres hacerlo recargando la página o lo quieres hacer sin recargarla?

Comment: @JoseJavierSegura Sin recargar la página

Comment: cuando dices _"en la misma página"_ te refieres a no refrescar el navegador? Si ese es el caso yo te recomendaría utilizar AJAX.

Comment: @JesseR.Jose Si exactamente eso me refiero, y lo estoy implementando pero no es lo deseado necesito es poder llamar una plantilla no el valor del label del radio del seleccionado...

Comment: Si he entendido bien ¿tú quieres pasar a PHP el valor de `variable` y según ese valor mostrar el contenido de una plantilla en alguna parte de la página actual, en `#div_producto`? Si es así, tu petición Ajax es casi correcta: yo agregaría un `dataType: 'html'` y aquí: `$('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);` en vez de `valor_radio` tendría que poner: `$('#div_producto').html(resp);`. Quizá el evento deba ser lanzando desde el `on.change` de los radio button implicados.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si según el valor del radio mostrar ese dato de la plantilla en alguna parte del sitio, esto de aquí `type: "POST",` es muy aparte de `dataType: 'html'`

Comment: Sí, `dataType` indica el tipo de datos que esperas en respuesta del servidor (html, json, script...), mientras que `type` es el tipo de petición que haces al servidor: `POST, GET, PUT...`. Por cierto, si al servidor envías: `saveTemp.php?step=' + step`  por `POST`, en el PHP la variable que vas a evaluar en el `switch` debes recuperarla así: `$variable=$_POST['step'];`, pero antes usar  `isset` para verificar que la variable fue posteada, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano Comprendido, no comprendo muy bien el envío de datos, pero lo que hace es recibirlo por `POST` y luego lo paso aún proceso de método `GET` observa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96689/cómo-validar-datos-del-proceso-wizard-con-php) el código que estoy trabajando es de la respuesta

Comment: Si lo envías por POST, debes recuperarlo por POST, no por GET. De todos modos, la respuesta dada por @JoseJavierSegura me parece la forma más sencilla de hacerlo. A través de `load` tú puedes cargar contenido de otras páginas en el documento actual. Lo que pasa es que él puso `expression` en el `switch`, si lo cambias por `valor` y todo lo demás está bien, te cargará el contenido deseado según lo que haya en la variable `valor`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entiendo ahora estoy haciendo practicas del código por medio de `json` y esta casi funcionando, pero necesito terminar de realizarlo para ver si existen fallos... Lo de recuperar datos por POST ya es otro problema que tendré que aclarar en una pregunta nueva sobre todo es un tema de problemas de seguridad al manipular un usuario malicioso los pasos enviados por `saveTemp.php?step=' + step`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías hacer las siguientes modificaciones:

- En parte donde generas con `PHP` las opciones de formas de pago (`eg: los radios`), para evitar duplicar código, podrías agregar solo el atributo `checked` cuando se cumpla la condición.

  ```
  <?php
  $r =array(
      1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
      2 => 'PayPal',
      3 => 'Tarjeta de credito',
  );

  foreach ($r as $key => $value) {

      $checked = '';
      if(isset($_SESSION['datos_form']['radio']) && $_SESSION['datos_form']['radio'] == $key ) {
          $checked = ' checked="checked"';
      }
      echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'"'.$checked.'>';
      echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
  } ?>

  <!-- AQUI en este elemento se cargará el contenido obtenido via AJAX -->
  <div id="formaPagoCont"></div>
  ```
- Para detectar el cambio de `radio` seleccionado y cargar el contenido correspondiente, podrías hacerlo así:

  ```
  // Cuando se haga click sobre algún `<input name="radio"`
  $('input[name="radio"]').on('click', () => {

    // Si el radio no esta seleccionado
    if (!this.checked) {
      return false;
    }

    // Solicitamos al archivo `formaPago.php` el contenido 
    // correspondiente al método de pago seleccionado
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'formaPago.php',
        data: {
          idForma: this.value
        }
      })
      .done(function(res) {
          // Si todo va bien, incluimos dentro del 
          // `<div id="formaPagoCont"` el contenido
          $('#formaPagoCont').html(res);
      });
  });
  ```
- Por ultimo, en el archivo `formaPago.php` (*archivo que deberías crear y el nombre podría ser cualquier otro*) solo quedaría por controlar el valor de `$_POST['idForma']` y devolver el contenido correspondiente. El código dentro del archivo `formaPago.php`, podría ser el siguiente:

  ```
  <?php
  switch ($_POST['idForma']) {
      case 1:
          # code... transferencia bancaria
          include 'wire_transfer.php';
          break;

      case 2:
          # code... Pago con paypal
          include 'payment_paypal.php';
          break;

      case 3:
          # code... tarjeta de crédito o débito 
          include 'form_credit_card.php';
          break;

      default:
          # code...
          echo "Hubo un error inesperado en la forma de pago seleccionada, vuelva intentarlo más tarde";
          break;
  }
  ```

Comment: aún no comprendo la solución, que se supone que debe ir en `url: 'formaPago.php',` el `switch` o otra cosa.

Comment: @J.Doe, en el archivo `formaPago.php`, deberías poner el código del `switch`, es decir, lo que esta en el último punto de mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La primera parte, para obtener el valor del radio pulsado, sería lo mismo que viste en tu pregunta.

Una vez obtenido el valor, ya puedes cargar el fichero php, a través del evento load de jquery.

Lo único que al ser por `javascript`, se ejecutará del lado del cliente, con lo que si el fichero `PHP`, lleva código de servidor, no se ejecutará

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(event){
        var valor = $(event.target).val();
        switch(expression) {
             case 1:
                $("#capa").load('form_credit_card.php');
                break;
            case 2:
                $("#capa").load('payment_paypal.php');
                break;
            case 3:
                $("#capa").load('wire_transfer.php');
                break;
            default:
                $("#capa").html('Hubo un error inesperado en la forma de pago seleccionada, vuelva intentarlo más tarde');
       }
    });
});
```

Para esto deberías crear un `div` que tenga por `id` el nombre de `capa`

Comment: No funciona, no muestra nada en el `div`

Comment: Debes cambiar: `switch(expression) {`  por: **`switch(valor) {`** @J.Doe

Comment: @A.Cedano No funciona, me muestra solo el valor por `default` y por último si llego a actualizar la página ese valor se pierde...